# Excel interop automation periodically freezes for 40-60 seconds

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

My program uses C# and interop to create complex Excel documents. The generation process runs against an invisible background instance of Excel. One particular interop call sometimes runs incredibly slowly. Most individual interop commands take just a few milliseconds, but assigning to the [Font.Bold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.font.bold) property can sometimes take 40-60s.

The 'slow' runs of this line of code are intermittent but follow a pattern. After a slow run, all successive runs will be fast for about 7-10 minutes, after which the next call will be slow. It is like there is a 'timer' which is reset on each slow run. While the timer is counting down all interop runs smoothly. Once the timer has expired, the next assignment to `Font.Bold` will be slow. It will be slow no matter whether the call comes immediately after the timer has expired, or if I leave the computer idle for a couple of hours and run the code again.

Restarting my program has no impact on this invisible timer. In other words I can run my code, wait for a slow run, and then exit the process. Then if I immediately start my code again, I will get fast runs for the next 7-10 minutes. I have ensured there are no instances of Excel or other Office apps running, including hidden ones lingering in the background. The only thing which 'resets' the timer is restarting my machine. It is like the timer exists on a system level outside of Excel or my code.

This applies in Debug and Release solution configurations, running with and without the debugger attached.

There is one other crucial piece of evidence. If I manually open an instance of Excel from the Start menu (i.e. driving it using mouse and keyboard rather than interop), there are repro steps for what looks like the same problem.

1. Create blank workbook
2. In the `Home` ribbon click `Cell Styles`
3. Right-click a style and click `Modify...`
4. Click the `Format...` button
5. Excel completely freezes for 40-60 seconds, then finally the dialog opens and behaves as normal

The freeze in the final step follows the same 7-10 minute cooldown behaviour as when I assign to the `Font.Bold` property in interop. The invisible 'timer' in the background is apparently *shared* between the Excel dialog and the interop code. In other words a slow run in interop will be followed by 7-10 minutes of Excel not freezing. And a frozen dialog in Excel is followed by 7-10 minutes of fast interop.

I have phrased this question as one about interop since that is how I first came across the problem. It may in fact just be a general Excel problem or bug, but it was only after many fruitless days of debugging my code, trying desperate garbage collection/`Marshal.ReleaseComObject` nonsense etc. that I discovered the Excel GUI symptom.

What is causing this slowness and what can I do about it?

Windows version: Windows 10 Home 21H1 (19043.2006)
Excel version: version 2209 Build 16.0.15629.20152 64-bit

Comment: Don't use Excel interop in the first place. If you want to create Excel files you can use libraries like EPPlus, ClosedXML, NPOI and more to do this without requiring Excel

Comment: There's no timer anyway. COM interop is single threaded, so if you do or start something that takes a lot of time, you won't be able to do anything until it finishes. `just a few milliseconds` for every property access is *huge*, which is why property access needs to be minimal. Every time you use `Sheet.Cells(1,1).Style......` you're performing more and more remote calls. Storing the object you want locally and modifying its properties reduces the remote calls. Constructing the object in your code and then assigning it to a root property is even faster

Comment: `is apparently shared between the Excel dialog and the interop code` the dialog blocks the operation, not any imagined timer. Your code asked Excel to do something that involves a dialog box and Excel is doing just that. Excel can't finish until that dialog goes away, so your own code will have to wait for Excel to complete

Answer (score 2):

I have a partial answer or at least explanation to my own question.

My deduction is, Excel hangs while trying to contact an offline printer. Work around the problem by setting the Windows default printer to one which is available.

The key was finding a [post](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/excel-freezes-when-formatting-cells/m-p/1712978) (archive [1](http://web.archive.org/web/20220406120214/https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/excel-freezes-when-formatting-cells/m-p/1712978), [2](https://archive.ph/qBzSt)) where someone describes the Excel freezing dialog symptom, and suggests changing the system default printer. My Windows default printer was set to a network-attached HP LaserJet which Windows `Printers & scanners` says is `Online` even though it's not been connected to the network or powered on in months. Changing the default printer to `Microsoft Print to PDF` eliminated the hangs both from interop and the live usage of Excel GUI.

This is speculation, but I imagine when the freeze happens Excel is trying to contact the printer, perhaps to determine which [device fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/printer-device-fonts) it supports. The Excel GUI thread (!) is ultimately blocked on a network call which times out. The 40-60 seconds is presumably the network timeout on trying to reach the printer, and the 7-10 minute 'timer' is an actual OS-wide timer which says 'if connection to a network printer fails assume it is unreachable and don't try to contact it again in this interval'.

I've tried on another machine with a different offline default printer, but I could not reproduce. Presumably the problem is only with specific printer drivers.

I'm not sure what can be done to prevent this problem in the wild when the code is running on other systems. Hopefully the problematic configuration is rare. I feel the blame could equally lie with Excel, a printer driver, or the Windows OS, so a bug fix seems unlikely.

Comment: The problem is the code and using Excel interop to create or modify a file, not Excel itself or any timer (there isn't one). COM automation is single-threaded (apartment-threaded specifically). This has nothing to do with GUI threads. Reading or writing a property is actually a cross-process call and hence *very* slow. You didn't post any code, but if you use Excel Interop to convert Excel to PDF you're executing a slow operation

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the question states that the problem manifests also when using Excel normally, and not just via interop. 'The Excel GUI thread' in this answer refers to when running Excel live with a mouse and keyboard, and experiencing a UI freeze.